# same table count union

Tags: mysql, count, union

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalHappenings FROM `happenings` WHERE `userId` = ? 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) as xHappenings FROM `happenings` WHERE `userId` = ? AND `destinationObjectType` = \'2\' 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) as yHappenings FROM `happenings` WHERE `userId` = ? AND `destinationObjectType` = \'1\'
```

Since it's the same table, and I don't wanna pass through 3 times the userId parameter how can I solve this the best way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Give an example of the results you are getting, and then the result you expect to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS totalHappenings,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `destinationObjectType` = \'2\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS xHappenings, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN `destinationObjectType` = \'1\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yHappenings 
FROM `happendings` 
WHERE `userId` = ?
```

Result:

```
totalHappenings xHappenings yHappenings
      24            10          14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with if statements inside select clause:

```
  SELECT
    COUNT(userId) as totalHappenings, 
    SUM(IF(`destinationObjectType`='2',1,0) as xHappenings,
    SUM(IF(`destinationObjectType`='1',1,0) as yHappenings
  FROM `happenings`
  WHERE `userId` = ?
```

This will surely return your results in 3 columns. Your original query was returning in 3 rows but I think that is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

try the shortest way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalHappenings, SUM(`destinationObjectType` = \'2\') AS xHappenings, SUM(`destinationObjectType` = \'1\') AS yHappenings FROM `happenings` WHERE `userId` = ?
```

comparision inside `SUM` returns true or false (1 or 0) so there is no need for `IF` or `CASE` statements

Comment: Good point - I'd forgotten this as I use it a lot for a scoring system, so I actually have multiple CASE parts to give differing scores.